# How to declare a function that has a structure containing an array, whose size is determined by argv, as an argument?

Tags: c, declaration

I have a structure `dt` that contains an internal array whose size is determined by `argv`. I need to feed this structure to a function `func` so I tried to declare it with a void pointer argument but the compiler is complaining that it's not being void at the end of the day. Here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void func(void *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int RETSIZE;
    sscanf(*++argv, "%d", &RETSIZE);
    struct
    {
        char name[6];
        char ret[RETSIZE];
    } dt[100];

    func(dt);
}

void func(void *dt)
{
    dt->ret[2] = 3;
}
```

How and where do I declare the structure `dt` and the function `func` so it works out ?

Comment: Do you _need_ an array? using a pointer would make your life easier.

Comment: @SouravGhosh There are few places where that phrase fits (considering that using pointers almost *never* makes ones life easier), but this seems to be one of them. :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Right sir, seems here, flexible array member is the way to go. :)

Comment: `malloc` is your friend here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_OBJECT 100
typedef struct
{
    char name[6];
    char ret[];
} dt;

void func(dt *strPtr)
{
    strPtr->ret[2] = 3;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    dt obj[MAX_OBJECT];

    func(&obj[0]);

    printf("Verify values written successfully or not: %d \n",obj[0].ret[2]); //Just for example
}
```

Comment: actually I don't even need to pass the structure as a paramater since it is declared in the global scope it is naturally avalaible to the function

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a structure in two (or more) functions, you need to define it in the *global* scope, so both functions have access to it. There's simply no way around it.

As for the array, in this case it's not possible to use variable-length arrays. You need to either use a [*flexible array member*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) or to use a pointer. Both of these requires dynamic allocation of the heap. You also need to keep the number of elements in the array as a member in the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few corrections/comments for your code:
 - Keep the struct in global scope so that the struct is visible to all the whole code.
 - In the func `void func(void *dt)`, you should again type cast it the original datatype(struct in this case), in order to use it.
 - As suggested in the above post, in C lang the size of the array(string) should be known to the compiler. Or else some garbage value will be present in `RETSIZE` and that much amount of stack memory is allocated to the `ret`. So, the struct should be 
`struct mystruct
    {
        char name[6];
        char *ret;
    };`
And for memory allocation,
`dt.ret = (char *)malloc(RETSIZE*sizeof(char));`
 - Also your `func` should be modifed cuz you have declared an struct array of 100, and you are passing it to the `func`